# How to set curve to the labels in the Highchart Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm using **Highcharts** JS library for drawing a pie chart where I have to show some labels in **circular** format. In my case, it's name of projects which I wanted to show in it's own block aligned with arc. See my code here [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/)

I've tried with some other JS libraries like *CircleType* and *Arctext* to give the curve shape for these labels. But for this, the attribute ID needs to be set for the particular text which I'm not able to do. By modifying Highcharts.js, I can manage to set ID for the Title of chart and when I set the property like `jQuery('#myid').arctext({radius: 50, rotate: true});` the title disappears.

So is it feasible to do this task in the graph?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why you cannot use loop and rotate datalabels like in second serie?

Comment: Because, I can't do it by setting only x and y positions. Also I didn't find any other option there which will give me the required result.

Comment: So these labels should be not rotated but "radiused?" Can you add mockup of your chart?

Comment: Okay. here is a link of a sample image where the curved labels are shown in a chart. [link](http://adaptivemarketing.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Adaptive-Productizing-Process1.gif) . And I've already tried to give curves to the edges but didn't find any way to do this.

Comment: The simplest way is calcualte degrees (as you have) and then call rotation attribute (SVG) which do this. Obviosuly you can adapt translation. Example http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/3/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Is it possible to give curves to these titles?

Comment: Do you mean curves like shapes or liek [this](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FSVG%2FElement%2FtextPath&ei=wL80VYCBBYL8aNiggdAP&usg=AFQjCNEkQJ-q5xogn6VndLQzGlOj3Pw43Q&sig2=OKR5URv-Q_E4AU-XLnNbgw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGg&cad=rja) ?

Comment: curve like shape, so that the label can be aligned with the curve of the slice in chart. Is it feasible?